# How to pass unicode text message through Popen.communicate()?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unicode, subprocess

I have python script which display Unicode message to the terminal while executing. So i want to display that message in the web page while the process runs. I was able to run the script through Popen package but its communicate() method which receives the output of the scripts can't receive Unicode text.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: \'charmap\' codec can\'t encode characters in position 12-15: character maps to <undefined>\r\n'
```

So i try to pass the message as bytes which can pass through it but i can't decode it later to discuss about this question go to: 
[How to decode a string representation of a bytes object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889234/how-to-decode-a-string-representation-of-a-bytes-object/)

But Now in this post i want to know the way to pass Unicode text through `Popen.communicate()`
My code here is

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
scripts = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'scripts')
p = Popen(["python", "tasks.py"],bufsize=0, cwd=scripts, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: I'd suggest making sure all your processes are running in UTF-8 locales, or setting the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to `UTF-8` for each process.  The problem you are having is that your system's default encoding isn't able to encode all the characters that you're passing around.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment of @snakecharmerb is the solution.

You must set the PYTHONIOENCODING variable before launching the child Python process to allow it to correctly encode its output in UTF-8. Then you have just to decode what you get in the parent:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'UTF-8'
scripts = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'scripts')
p = Popen(["python", "tasks.py"],bufsize=0, cwd=scripts, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate()
print(out.decode())
```

If you have Python>=3.6, you can directly get out and err as unicode strings:

```
os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'UTF-8'
scripts = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'scripts')
p = Popen(["python", "tasks.py"],bufsize=0, cwd=scripts, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding='UTF-8')
out,err = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked just by putting the line which sets pythonencoding to UTF-8